# Google Maps Places Search, calculate distance to each result

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm currently making an app for a university assignment. I'm using the google maps places api and gmaps.js.

What I want to do is let user search places and show the results in a simple list (which I've got working) but I want to calculate the distance to each of the search results as well, which is sort of working (I think!) but I'm not sure how to make it display how I want, e.g:

- "Search Result - 1.1 mi away"
- "Search Result - 0.8 mi away"

What it is doing right now is calculating the distances but all the values are being set next to all of the search results, instead of next to each other. In one line (all bunched together).

(Had to remove a link to post a new one)

I don't know how to split them or do it more cleanly from the start. I think the problem lies in the function which is calculating the distances using "google.maps.DistanceMatrixService".

```
            var origin = currentLocation;
            var destination = place.geometry.location;
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

                    service.getDistanceMatrix({
                        origins: [origin],
                        destinations: [destination],
                        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
                        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                        avoidHighways: false,
                        avoidTolls: false
                    }, getDistance);

                    function getDistance(response, status) {
                        if (status == "OK") {

                            var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text; 

                            console.log(distance);

                            $(".distance").append(distance);

                        } else {
                            return false;
                            console.log(response + status)
                        }
                    }

                    getDistance();
```

This line is my best guess:

```
response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
```

But I'm quite lost with it.

Full code of my search request:

```
    $("#place-search").submit(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
    var query = $("#place-query").val();

    map.addLayer("places", {
        location: cheltenham, //new google.maps.LatLng(51.902707,-2.073361),
        radius: 500, //experiment with the distance (in metres)
        query: query,
        opennow: true,

        textSearch: function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                $(".results-list").html(""); //remove previous results

                removeMarkers(); //remove previous markers

                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                //console.log(bounds);

                //I think if we set i to say 10, it will limit the search results - by default the places api returns 20 result sets
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    //console.log(i);
                    var place = results[i];

                    var image = { //set to better sizes and positions (icons from search results)
                        url: place.icon,
                        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                    };

                    /* ---------- */

                    var origin = currentLocation; //new google.maps.LatLng(51.902707,-2.073361);
                    var destination = place.geometry.location; //new google.maps.LatLng(51.899464, -2.074641);
                    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

                    service.getDistanceMatrix({
                        origins: [origin],
                        destinations: [destination],
                        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING, //this needs to be a choice
                        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                        avoidHighways: false,
                        avoidTolls: false
                    }, getDistance);

                    function getDistance(response, status) {
                        if (status == "OK") {

                            var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text; //the one I need 

                            console.log(distance);

                            $(".distance").append(distance);

                        } else {
                            return false;
                            console.log(response + status)
                        }
                    }

                    getDistance();

                    /* ---------- */


                    map.addMarker({
                        lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
                        lng: place.geometry.location.lng(),
                        icon: image,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        title: place.name,

                        //we need to style and build these better - ideas? should be simple I think, Name + Location + Image
                        infoWindow: {
                            content: '<h2>'+place.name+'</h2>' + '<p>Rating: '+place.rating+'</p>' +  '<p>'+(place.vicinity ? place.vicinity : place.formatted_address)+'</p><img src="'+place.icon+'"" width="100"/>'
                        }   
                    });

                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);

                    $(".results-list").append("<li>" + place.name + "<span class=\"distance\"></span></li>");

                }
                map.fitBounds(bounds); //fit to the new bounds
            }//end if search OK
        }
    }); 
});
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Update:

I've tried moving the line that puts the items into the list with jQuery into the function getDistance(), and that ends up putting the distances with the place name but it's the same place name for every distance that is calculated. It is the last result from the search.

**getDistance()**

```
function getDistance(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {

        var origins = response.originAddresses;
        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

        for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
            var results = response.rows[i].elements;

                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    var element = results[j];
                    var distance = element.distance.text;
                    var duration = element.duration.text;

                    var from = origins[i];
                    var to = destinations[j];

                    $(".results-list").append("<li><span class=\"name\">" + place.name + "</span>" + distance + "</li>") 
                }
        }
    } else {
        return false;
        console.log(response + status)
    }
}
```

What the output looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKB64.png

Thanks to everyone who's taken a look so far!

Comment: [Example places search with distance and time](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_10minuteDriveG.html?address=Bronx,NY)

Comment: Thanks for the example, I've tried a few things from it but all seem to result in the same thing. I can't really see what I'm doing wrong. I just keep getting the all the distances for every location together (like in the screenshot).